# ImageView spread out animation

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, canvas

I basically have an ImageView which got modified with `Canvas` and looks like a cirlce. (original image had the dimensions of a square (500x500))

Image what the starting position looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtcMB.jpg
(red is transparent and got removed with help of the `Canvas` method)

The animation should take aroud 1000 miliseconds and during this time step for step restore to the original picture. So in the end there should be a sqaure again.

In other words the cut off corners, which are the differnce between a square and a circle (and red marked in the image), get step for step restored in around 1000 milliseconds, with a sort of spreading looking animation.

Don't really have any clue on how to achieve this, so I can just share the `Canvas` method I used to cut off the corners (if it helps :X):

```
private Bitmap createCircleImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap bmp;

        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        float radius = bitmap.getWidth() / 2f;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(shader);

        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Appreciate any help,
thank you!

Comment: so you posted the image what the starting position and whats the final position?

Comment: @pskink the square(picture's original size) since the square got modified with the canvas method, which I posted, it looks like a circle.This is also my current state and works fine. However what I want is the circle to get back to his original form/size (the square) with a sort of spreading animation. :)

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you really want

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve such behavior. For example you can create custom view and override its onDraw method such as

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawCircle(viewWidth/2, viewHeight/2, currentRadius, paint);

}
```

and then you can just increase the radius little by little and invalidate the view.Since view is by default will clip on its clipBounds (you can only draw inside viewidth x viewheight rectangle unless you set it otherwise) you will get the effect that you want. And then you can tweak the interpolation to achieve smoother and more natural animation.

note: a bitmap shader is attached to the paint (you already know chow to create it). I don't include it in the code, since you shouldn't initialize it inside onDraw method for performance reason.